# Determine expired trial subscription on stripe when customer.subscription.deleted arrives

Tags: stripe-payments, payment

I allow free 30-day trials for my subscriptions which is managed by `cancel_at_period_end` flag set to `true`.  I also have a webhook listening for `customer.subscription.deleted` event. In this hook I need the way to know that subscription was deleted by stripe after 30-days trial? How can I do that without storing extra information in my DB. I assume when it gets deleted the next is correct `eventObject.ended_at === eventObject.trial_end`? Is it really safe to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `eventObject.ended_at === eventObject.trial_end` to check whether a subscription ended/was cancelled at the end of the subscriptions trial.